# How to solve a system of linear equations with sums only, with $NP$ equations and $N+P$ unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have $NP$ equations in the form:
$$y_{n,p} = x_{n} + b_{p},$$
with $n = 0, 1, ..., N$ and $p = 0, 1, ..., P$.

I know each $y_{n,p}$, but I don't know any $x_{n}$ or any $b_{p}$. I would like to determine each $x_{n}$ from the $y_{n,p}$. I don't need to know $b_{p}$.
Since I have $NP$ linear equations for $N+P$ unknowns, I would expect a solution as long as $NP \geq N+P$ (which is verified as soon as $N\geq 2$ and $P\geq 2$).

For example,  with $N=3$ and $P=2$, we have
$$\left\{\begin{aligned} y_{1,1} &= x_{1} + b_{1} \\
                         y_{2,1} &= x_{2} + b_{1} \\
                         y_{3,1} &= x_{3} + b_{1} \\
                         y_{1,2} &= x_{1} + b_{2} \\
                         y_{2,2} &= x_{2} + b_{2} \\
                         y_{3,2} &= x_{3} + b_{2}
\end{aligned} \right.$$

This is different than traditional systems of linear equations, since only additions are involved. It looks very simple, but I cannot find a way to solve it, and in fact I am not sure we can solve it. I can play with the equations to eliminate the $b_p$ (e.g. $y_{2,1} - y_{1,1} = x_{2} - x_{1}$) or the $x_n$ (e.g. $y_{1,2} - y_{1,1} = b_{2} - b_{1}$), but I don't see how to express each $x_n$ from $y_{n,p}$ only.

Comment: You need $N P = N + P$ to make it solvable since there are $NP$ equations, $N$ values $x$, and $P$ values $b$.

Comment: In this case, only $N=2$ and $P=2$ would lead to a solvable system.  How to prove that we need an equality? Even with $N=2$ and $P=2$, I still don't see how to express $x_1$ and $x_2$ from $y_{1,1}$, $y_{1,2}$, $y_{2,1}$, $y_{2,2}$ only.

Comment: In general $NP > N+P$ which means you need to do regression (curve-fitting). This is possible in a linear system using the [pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse)

Comment: Yes a typical linear system $\boldsymbol{Ax}=\boldsymbol{b}$, where the matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ and the vector $\boldsymbol{b}$ are known, can be solved as $\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{A}^{+} \boldsymbol{b}$ with $\boldsymbol{A}^{+}$ the pseudo-inverse of $\boldsymbol{A}$. But here, I have $\boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{1}_{P \times 1} \otimes \boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{b} \otimes \boldsymbol{1}_{N \times 1}$, with $\boldsymbol{x} = [x_1 x_2 \cdots x_N]^\mathrm{T}$, same for $b$, where only the vector $\boldsymbol{y}$ is known, and the vectors $\boldsymbol{x}$ are $\boldsymbol{b}$ are unknown.

Comment: You need to linearize the problem by making $$\boldsymbol{w} = [x_1,x_2,\ldots,b_1,b_2,\ldots]$$ and forming the problem as $$\boldsymbol{y} = {\bf A} \boldsymbol{w}$$

Unfortunately when I try it with $N=2, P=2$ the system is singular and there are infinite solutions for $\boldsymbol{w}$.

Comment: Indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem as stated, does not have a solution.

I will use the $N=2$ and $P=3$ example to illustrate why

$$\begin{bmatrix}y_{1,1}\\
y_{1,2}\\
y_{1,3}\\
y_{2,1}\\
y_{2,2}\\
y_{2,3}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\
1\\
1\\
 & 1\\
 & 1\\
 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\
x_{2}
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}1\\
 & 1\\
 &  & 1\\
1\\
 & 1\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b_{1}\\
b_{2}\\
b_{3}
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}$$

I assign names to the above vectors and matrices such as the expression below is the same as the expression above

$$ \boldsymbol{y}={\rm G}\boldsymbol{x}+{\rm H}\boldsymbol{b} \tag{1} $$

where $\boldsymbol{x} = [x_1,x_2 \ldots x_N]$, $\boldsymbol{b} = [b_1,b_2,\ldots b_P]$, and $\boldsymbol{y} = [y_{1,1}\ldots, y_{N,P}]$

Note the projections below

$$\begin{gathered}{\rm G}^{\intercal}{\rm G}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\
 & 3
\end{bmatrix}=P\;{\bf 1}\\
{\rm H}^{\intercal}{\rm H}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\
 & 2\\
 &  & 2
\end{bmatrix}=M\;{\bf 1}\\
{\rm G}^{\intercal}{\rm H}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{gathered}
\tag{2}$$

<sub>Here ${\bf 1}$ denotes an identity matrix.</sub>

Using the above projections we can eliminate one the two unknown vectors at a time to try to solve for the other one

$$\begin{gathered}{\rm G}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{y}=P\boldsymbol{x}+{\rm G}^{\intercal}{\rm H}\boldsymbol{b}\\
\boldsymbol{x}=\tfrac{1}{P}{\rm G}^{\intercal}\left(\boldsymbol{y}-{\rm H}\boldsymbol{b}\right)\\
\left({\bf 1}-{\rm G}\tfrac{1}{P}{\rm G}^{\intercal}\right)\boldsymbol{y}=\underbrace{\left({\bf 1}-{\rm G}\tfrac{1}{P}{\rm G}^{\intercal}\right)}_{\text{singular}}{\rm H}\boldsymbol{b}
\end{gathered} \tag{3}$$

and

$$ \begin{gathered}{\rm H}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{y}={\rm H}^{\intercal}{\rm G}\boldsymbol{x}+N\boldsymbol{b}\\
\boldsymbol{b}=\tfrac{1}{N}{\rm H}^{\intercal}\left(\boldsymbol{y}-{\rm G}\boldsymbol{x}\right)\\
\left({\bf 1}-{\rm H}\tfrac{1}{N}{\rm H}^{\intercal}\right)\boldsymbol{y}=\underbrace{\left({\bf 1}-{\rm H}\tfrac{1}{N}{\rm H}^{\intercal}\right)}_{\text{singular}}{\rm G}\boldsymbol{x}
\end{gathered} \tag{4}$$

Unfortunately, the singular coefficient matrix in front of the unknown vectors prevents us from solving the problem, regardless of the values for $N$ and $P$. Even the $N=P=2$ situation results in an underconstrained problem.